# SFTP upload Could not open file/Failure creating remote file

Tags: php

I can't upload my file through SFTP but I can download the file? In the end I'll have to send the file through SFTP to another SFTP location then I'm currently uploading to. I have all rights to write in all folders in my test environment where I'm currently getting the bug. The directories that I'm writing into have 777 as rights.

The server is using PHP7.0.

My code can connect to the SFTP and login.

```
protected $connection;
protected $sftp;
public function __construct($server,$username,$pass){
        $port=22;

        $this->connection = @ssh2_connect($server, $port);

        if (!$this->connection){

            throw new Exception("Could not connect to ".$server." on port".$port.".");

        } else {

            $this->login($username,$pass);

        }
    }

    public function login($username, $password){
        if (! @ssh2_auth_password($this->connection, $username, $password)){
            throw new Exception("Could not authenticate with username ".$username);
        }
        $this->sftp = @ssh2_sftp($this->connection);
        if(!$this->sftp){
            throw new Exception("Could not initialize SFTP subsystem.");
        }
    }
```

Here is the function to upload my file. When I'm using ssh2_scp_send($sftp, $local_file, $remote_file, 0644); I get the error:

> **Warning**:  ssh2_scp_send(): Failure creating remote file:
>   (null) in **/var/www/html/scripts/class.sftp.php** on line
>   **45**

When I use @fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp$remote_file", 'w');
I get the error:

> Could not open file:$remote_file.

```
public function uploadFile($local_file, $remote_file){
 $sftp = $this->connection;
            try{
                ssh2_scp_send($sftp, $local_file, $remote_file, 0644);
                ssh2_exec($sftp, 'exit');
                return true;
            }catch(Exception $oErr) {
                print __CLASS__ . ", method uploadFile (in class.sftp van SAN) foutmelding:\n"
                                . " regel ". $oErr->getLine() . ": " . $oErr->getMessage() ."\n ";
            }
            /*try{
                $stream = @fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp$remote_file", 'w');
                if (!$stream){
                    throw new Exception("Could not open file:".$remote_file);
                }
                $data_to_send = @file_get_contents($local_file);
                if($data_to_send === false){
                    throw new Exception("Could not open local file:".$local_file);
                }
                if(@fwrite($stream, $data_to_send) === false){
                    throw new Exception("Could not send data from file:".$local_file);
                }
                @fclose($stream);
            }catch(Exception $oErr) {
                print __CLASS__ . ", method uploadFile (in class.sftp van SAN) foutmelding:\n"
                                . " regel ". $oErr->getLine() . ": " . $oErr->getMessage() ."\n ";
            }*/
```

This is the download function which works without a problem.

```
public function getFile($local_file,$remote_file){
        $sftp = $this->connection;
        ssh2_scp_recv($sftp, $remote_file, $local_file);
        return true;
}
```

The download works with ssh2_scp_recv but not through fopen. So I expected ssh2_scp_send to work as well.

```
public function getFile($local_file,$remote_file){
    /*$stream = @fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp$remote_file", 'r');
            if(!$stream){
                return false;
                throw new Exception("Could not open file: $remote_file");
            }
            $size = $this->getFileSize($remote_file);
            $contents = '';
            $read = 0;
            $len = $size;
            while ($read < $len && ($buf = fread($stream, $len - $read))) {
                $read += strlen($buf);
                $contents .= $buf;
            }
            file_put_contents($local_file, $contents);
            @fclose($stream);*/
}
```

Comment: Here's my opinion based comment. Ditch that built in ssh library and use http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/. I've had so many problems with the ssh2 lib over the years, I finally ditched it and I haven't had a single issue.

Comment: do you have a full path for the remote file?

Comment: @verhie I use a /var/www/html/X path for my remote and local file to test. But since it's a working server I can't use the path names here for security reasons. The download function can place to file into another folder on the same SFTP so I know for sure that the code can reach the file and can write to the directory that I'm using.

Comment: @mkaatman Thank you for the recommendation, trying it out right away.

Comment: I spent a full day working on troubleshooting the [last time](http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/6439) they broke they're API and it only took a couple of hours to convert.